# oops installation initialization successful sql developer installlation message upon trying to install sql server developer 2019

Tags: sql-server-2019

[image]

I am trying to install SQL server developer 2019 edition and I get this issue.
I wanted to create a SQL server for my .NET API but when I checked it needed SQL server running in service but it wasn't so when I tried to download it doesn't download, it just checks for precious downloads and then immediately shows this message

My windows specification if that helps

```
Edition Windows 10 Home Single Language

Version 21H2

Installed on    ‎16-‎03-‎2021

OS build    19044.1645

Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4170.0
```

possible error issue:

```
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 DetectPreviousRulesDownloadActivityFatalException:  ExceptionMessage: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. TypeName: NullReferenceException StackTrace:    at Microsoft.Sql.Installer.Engine.Utils.GetDownloadFolder()
   at Microsoft.Sql.Installer.Engine.DetectPreviousDownloadActivity.RunActivity()
   at Microsoft.Sql.Installer.Engine.SetupEngine.ExecuteActivity(ActivityBase activity)
```

Full log:

```
(01) 2022-05-08 20:06:59 SSEI v15.2204.5490.2
(01) 2022-05-08 20:06:59 CorrelationId: 7f160959-3fcb-405c-b647-c2cff591ab3c
(01) 2022-05-08 20:06:59 Path for UserRequestedLocalAuditDirectory is null or doesn't exist: ''
(01) 2022-05-08 20:06:59 CurrentCulture.Name='en-IN'.LCID='16393'.Parent.Name='en'
(01) 2022-05-08 20:06:59 CurrentUICulture.Name='en-US'.LCID='1033'.Parent.Name='en'
(01) 2022-05-08 20:06:59 CurrentCulture has 'en' parent'.
(01) 2022-05-08 20:06:59 resolvedCulture: en-US
(01) 2022-05-08 20:06:59 osSupported: True, osVersion: 10.0.19044.0, osPlatform: amd64
(04) 2022-05-08 20:06:59 .NET Framework Version: 4.5
(04) 2022-05-08 20:06:59 StartupBootstrapActivity:SSEIActivityStart:Message: Starting Activity StartupBootstrapActivity
(04) 2022-05-08 20:06:59 StartupBootstrapActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 1
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 Downloading manifest from https://download.microsoft.com/download/d/a/2/da259851-b941-459d-989c-54a18a5d44dd/Manifest_Bootstrap_All.xml
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 Current version: '15.2204.5490.2', Minimum version: '15.2204.5490.2'
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 StartupBootstrapActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 100
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 StartupBootstrapActivity:SSEIActivityMessage:Message: Installation initialization successful
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 StartupBootstrapActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 100
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 StartupBootstrapActivity:SSEIActivityEnd:Message: Finishing Activity StartupBootstrapActivity
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 Activity Summaries for Scenario [InitializeBootstrapManifest]
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 ActivityName   Outcome WasCancelled    DurationSeconds
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 StartupBootstrapActivity   1   0   0.3018288
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 Found manifest resource: Manifest_Rules_All_en-US.xml
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 Found manifest resource: Manifest_Full_Dev_en-US.xml
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 Found manifest resource: Manifest_Media_Dev_zh-CN.xml
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 Found manifest resource: Manifest_Media_Dev_zh-TW.xml
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 Found manifest resource: Manifest_Media_Dev_en-US.xml
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 Found manifest resource: Manifest_Media_Dev_fr-FR.xml
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 Found manifest resource: Manifest_Media_Dev_de-DE.xml
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 Found manifest resource: Manifest_Media_Dev_it-IT.xml
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 Found manifest resource: Manifest_Media_Dev_ja-JP.xml
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 Found manifest resource: Manifest_Media_Dev_ko-KR.xml
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 Found manifest resource: Manifest_Media_Dev_pt-BR.xml
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 Found manifest resource: Manifest_Media_Dev_ru-RU.xml
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 Found manifest resource: Manifest_Media_Dev_es-ES.xml
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 BootstrapActivity:SSEIActivityStart:Message: Starting Activity BootstrapActivity
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 BootstrapActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 1
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 BootstrapActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 100
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 BootstrapActivity:SSEIActivityMessage:Message: Installation initialization successful
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 BootstrapActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 100
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 BootstrapActivity:SSEIActivityEnd:Message: Finishing Activity BootstrapActivity
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 SetupLocationActivity:SSEIActivityStart:Message: Starting Activity SetupLocationActivity
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 SetupLocationActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 1
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 SetupLocationActivity:SSEIActivityMessage:Message: Locating drive that meets space requirements (4418)
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 SetupLocationActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 100
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 SetupLocationActivity:SSEIActivityMessage:Message: Drive found: C:\ AvailableFreeSpace: 68335456256
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 SetupLocationActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 100
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 SetupLocationActivity:SSEIActivityEnd:Message: Finishing Activity SetupLocationActivity
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 Activity Summaries for Scenario [BootstrapInitialize]
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 ActivityName   Outcome WasCancelled    DurationSeconds
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 BootstrapActivity  1   0   0.0006613
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 SetupLocationActivity  1   0   0.0030637
(04) 2022-05-08 20:07:00 Collecting installed instances.
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 CheckBuiltInRulesActivity:SSEIActivityStart:Message: Starting Activity CheckBuiltInRulesActivity
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 CheckBuiltInRulesActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 1
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 CheckBuiltInRulesActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 100
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 CheckBuiltInRulesActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 100
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 CheckBuiltInRulesActivity:SSEIActivityEnd:Message: Finishing Activity CheckBuiltInRulesActivity
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 PreviousInstallActivity:SSEIActivityStart:Message: Starting Activity PreviousInstallActivity
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 PreviousInstallActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 1
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 PreviousInstallActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 100
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 PreviousInstallActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 100
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 PreviousInstallActivity:SSEIActivityEnd:Message: Finishing Activity PreviousInstallActivity
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 BootstrapRulesOnlyActivity:SSEIActivityStart:Message: Starting Activity BootstrapRulesOnlyActivity
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 BootstrapRulesOnlyActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 1
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 BootstrapRulesOnlyActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 100
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 BootstrapRulesOnlyActivity:SSEIActivityMessage:Message: Installation initialization successful
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 BootstrapRulesOnlyActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 100
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 BootstrapRulesOnlyActivity:SSEIActivityEnd:Message: Finishing Activity BootstrapRulesOnlyActivity
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 DetectPreviousRulesDownloadActivity:SSEIActivityStart:Message: Starting Activity DetectPreviousRulesDownloadActivity
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 DetectPreviousRulesDownloadActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 1
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 DetectPreviousRulesDownloadActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 100
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 DetectPreviousRulesDownloadActivity:SSEIActivityMessage:Message: 
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 DetectPreviousRulesDownloadActivityFatalException:  ExceptionMessage: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. TypeName: NullReferenceException StackTrace:    at Microsoft.Sql.Installer.Engine.Utils.GetDownloadFolder()
   at Microsoft.Sql.Installer.Engine.DetectPreviousDownloadActivity.RunActivity()
   at Microsoft.Sql.Installer.Engine.SetupEngine.ExecuteActivity(ActivityBase activity)
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 DetectPreviousRulesDownloadActivity:SSEIProgressReport:ProgressPercent: 100
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 DetectPreviousRulesDownloadActivity:SSEIActivityEnd:Message: Finishing Activity DetectPreviousRulesDownloadActivity
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 Activity Summaries for Scenario [BasicInstall]
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 ActivityName   Outcome WasCancelled    DurationSeconds
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 CheckBuiltInRulesActivity  1   0   0.1042338
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 PreviousInstallActivity    1   0   0.0024756
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 BootstrapRulesOnlyActivity 1   0   0.0001329
(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 DetectPreviousRulesDownloadActivity    0   0   0.0554809
```

Comment: Check the installation logs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/view-and-read-sql-server-setup-log-files?view=sql-server-ver15 and show us any relevant errors

Comment: @Charlieface this may be the reason

`(04) 2022-05-08 20:08:02 DetectPreviousRulesDownloadActivityFatalException:  ExceptionMessage: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. TypeName: NullReferenceException StackTrace:    at Microsoft.Sql.Installer.Engine.Utils.GetDownloadFolder()
   at Microsoft.Sql.Installer.Engine.DetectPreviousDownloadActivity.RunActivity()
   at Microsoft.Sql.Installer.Engine.SetupEngine.ExecuteActivity(ActivityBase activity)`

Comment: Try re downloading it, also try clear out any temporary folders. Often it's at `C:\SQLInstallMedia` or something similar

Answer (score 0):

Check installed programms (delete if this installed) and remove ms sql dirs and retry again

Comment: what did you mean by this? also did you mean delete everything in MICROSOFT SQL SERVER folder like specified here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/file-locations-for-default-and-named-instances-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Check C:\Program Files + (x86) and %ProgramData% %appdata% anything related to mssql delete! Check installed programs in control panel and delete mssql server if exists

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).